# Concerning $(x,y) \mapsto (\lambda x^2y+A,\mu x^{-1}+B)$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $f : (x,y) \mapsto (p,q)$ be a map from $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ to $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1},y]$ satisfying the following two conditions:

**(i)** $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q):=p_xq_y-p_yq_x \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

**(ii)** $l_{1,-1}(p)=\lambda x^2y$ and $l_{1,-1}(q)=\mu x^{-1}$, for some $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Then we can write $p=\lambda x^2y + A$ and $q=\mu x^{-1}+B$, where $v_{1,-1}(A)<1$ and  $v_{1,-1}(B) < -1$.

> Is it true that **(i)**+**(ii)** imply that $A=B=0$?

In other words, 
is it true that **(i)**+**(ii)** imply that $p=\lambda x^2y$ and $q=\mu x^{-1}$?

> Otherwise, could one find $f$ satisfying **(i)**+**(ii)** having $A \neq 0$ or $B \neq 0$?

---

**Edit:** Variations and generalizations on the above question:

**(1)** Taking $f: (x,y) \mapsto (\lambda x^{-1}y+A,\mu x^2+B)$.

**(2)** More generally, taking 
$f: (x,y) \mapsto (\lambda x^{n+1}y+A,\mu x^{-n}+B)$,
$0 \neq n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**(3)** Replacing $k[x,y] \to k[x,x^{-1},y]$ by $A_1(k) \to A_1(k)^{-1}$,
in all questions, especially the general case **(2)**.

Where $A_1(k)$ is the first Weyl algebra, namely, the associative non-commutative $k$-algebra generated by $x$ and $y$ subject to the relation $yx-xy=1$. And $A_1(k)^{-1}$ is the ring extension of $A_1(k)$ generated by $x,x^{-1},y$ subject to $yx-xy=1$, $xx^{-1}=x^{-1}x=1$ and $[y,x^{-1}]=-x^{-2}$.

**(4)** Considering $k[x^{1/r},x^{-1/r},y]$ instead of $k[x,x^{-1},y]$,
$r \in \mathbb{N}$. And considering $A_1(k)^{-1/r}$ instead of $A_1(k)^{-1}$.

Thank you veru much! I now asked the above question in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335655/concerning-x-y-mapsto-x-fracnr1y-a-mu-x-fracnrb).

Comment: Necessarily $B=0$, but you can have $A=p(x^{-1})$ for any polynomial $p$.

Comment: @san, thank you. I later realized your comment myself and asked (in June): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265981/if-x-y-mapsto-x1mya-x-mb-m-in-mathbbz-then-b-0