# If $(x,y) \mapsto (x^{1+m}y+a,x^{-m}+b)$, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $b=0$?

Tags: polynomials, jacobian

The following is a special case of my original question (perhaps it is better to first concentrate on this special case):

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$,
and $f: (x,y) \mapsto (p:=x^{1+m}y+a,q:=x^{-m}+b)$, a $k$-algebra homomorphism from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x,x^{-1/m},y]$ having a non-zero scalar Jacobian, namely, $\operatorname{Jac}(p,q):=p_xq_y-p_yq_x \in k-\{0\}$.

Here I assume that $l_{1,-1}(p)=x^{1+m}y$ and $l_{1,-1}(q)=x^{-m}$,
hence $\deg_{1,-1}(a)<m$ and $\deg_{1,-1}(b)<-m$.

**Claim:** Such $f$ necessarily satisfies: $a \in k[x,x^{-1}]$ (of appropriate $(1,-1)$-degree) and $b=0$.

I have a sketch of proof of that claim, based on considerations of $(1,-1)$-degrees and the Jacobians of the $(1,-1)$-homogeneous components of $a$ and $b$.

> Is the claim true, or can one find a counterexample?

Notice that $pq=xy+E$, where $\deg_{1,-1}(E) < 0$; perhaps this information may help?

Please also see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334247/concerning-certain-keller-maps-of-kx-y) question.

Any hints and comments are welcome! Thank you.

Comment: You really mean a homomorphism from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x,x^{-1/m},y]$, or is it from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x,x^{-1},y]$?

Comment: And you require $m>0$?

Comment: Because for $m>0$ one can prove that it is true, but for example for $m=-1$ you have $p=y+\frac{3 y^4}{x^2}$ and $q=x+\frac{12 y^3}{x}+\frac{24 y^6}{x^3}$.

Comment: @san, thanks for your comments. Here, I meant a homomorphism from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x,x^{-1},y]$. But actually I am interested in more general cases (including the first Weyl algebra): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335655/concerning-x-y-mapsto-x-fracnr1y-a-mu-x-fracnrb

Comment: Truly, I do not require that $m >0$. Your last comment shows that there is a counterexample, also to my more general question concerning a homomorphism from $k[x,y]$ to $k[x^{1/r},x^{-1/r},y]$.

Comment: For $m\in \Bbb{Q}$ the proposition is true for $m>0$, and for $m<0$ there are counterexamples.

Comment: @san, thanks, I understood that from your previous comment (I do not have a complete proof for $m>0$ myself). If you like to write an answer to my question (perhaps also in MO), that would be nice.  (Same answer for the first Weyl algebra?),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the language and results from [Gucc. et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.1784.pdf)
If $m>0$, then it suffices to prove that $\min\{Succ_P(1,-1),Succ_Q(1,-1)\}>(0,1)$ (See Definition 3.4 of [Gucc. et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.1784.pdf) for the definition of $Succ$).

Now assume by contradiction that
$$
(0,1)\ge (\rho,\sigma) :=\min\{Succ_P(1,-1),Succ_Q(1,-1)\}>(1,-1).
$$
Then $v_{\rho,\sigma}(p)>0\ge v_{\rho,\sigma}(q)$, and it follows that $en_{\rho,\sigma}(p)\nsim en_{\rho,\sigma}(q)$. By Proposition 2.4 of [Gucc. et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.1784.pdf) we have
$$
(0,0)=en_{\rho,\sigma}([p,q])=en_{\rho,\sigma}(p)+en_{\rho,\sigma}(q)-(1,1).
$$
Hence the only possibility is $en_{\rho,\sigma}(p)=(1+m,1)$ and $en_{\rho,\sigma}(q)=(0,-m)$, which contradicts the fact that either $\mathcal{l}_{\rho,\sigma}(p)$ or $\mathcal{l}_{\rho,\sigma}(q)$ is not a monomial (else $(\rho,\sigma)$ wouldn't be  $Succ_P$ nor $Succ_Q$.)

If $m<0$, then there are counterexamples, for example, if $m=-1$, then $p=y+\frac{3y^4}{x^2}$ and $q=x+\frac{12y^3}{x}+\frac{24y^6}{x^3}$ gives a counterexample.

For $m=-2$ we can take $p=x^{−1}y+3x^{−8}y^4$  and $q=x^2+12x^{−5}y^3+24x^{−12}y^6$.

For general $m$ we can take $p=y x^{1+m}+3y^4 x^{4+6 m}$
and $q=x^{-m}+12 y^3 x^{3+4 m}+24y^6 x^{6+9 m}$

For the extended Weyl algebra the proof for $m>0$ stands its ground, but the construction of counterexamples is a little bit trickier.

Comment: Thank you very much! (I am familiar with that paper).

Comment: Please, concerning possible counterexamples, namely, cases where $m < 0$: Can something interesting be said about the $(1,1)$-degrees or $(0,1)$-degrees of $p$ and $q$?

Comment: I would think that they can be nearly arbitrary.

Comment: It is very easy to produce counter examples that are $(\rho, \sigma)$-homogeneus for some $(\rho,\sigma)$, but one can even produce some which are not (but only with fractional powers of $x$.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Any further counterexamples are welcome.

Comment: In general, if you have a direction $(\rho, \sigma)$ such that $av_{\rho,\sigma}(1+m,1)=bv_{\rho,\sigma}(-m,0)$, for some coprime positive integers $a,b>1$, then for any positive integer $k$ you can find $(\rho,\sigma)$-homogeneus $p$ and $q$ such that $v_{01}(en_{\rho,\sigma}(p))=bk$ and $v_{01}(en_{\rho,\sigma}(q))=ak$. Necessarily en(p) and en(q) are aligned.

Comment: It should also be true that if $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ and en(p) and en(q) are integer valued, then you can  find p and q in $k[x,x^{-1},y]$.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was trying to find this result in some article or book, but it is nowhere to find. I thought it was folklore.

Comment: Thank you. I have other versions of this question, which I will probably ask soon (in a few hours/ days/ weeks).

Comment: If you do so, send me a message via this thread, because I usually only read featured questions.

Comment: This is very nice of you, thanks! I have posted the following question, which was answered partially (I was close to that answer myself). If you could complete that proof or find another proof, that would be interesting https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296019/form-of-x-y-mapsto-lambda-xn-cdots-mu-xn-cdots-in-kx1-m-x-1-m/3296089?noredirect=1#comment6780350_3296089

Comment: please, could you build a counterexample for $m=-2$ other than $p=x^{-1}y+T$ and $q=x^2$, where $T \in k[x^{1/m},x^{-1/m}]$; probably you think it is not difficult to find such a morphism.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for the hint!

Comment: Thank you very much for the new (counter)example!

Comment: I added an example to the post (the two examples in the comments were not corrrect).

Comment: Great! thank you very much for the general example.